# Estimate mutation rate in UVC treated cells

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, mutations, uv

I am wondering how to get a coarse estimate of the number of mutation I obtain doing UVC treatment on eukaryotic cells (microalgae) starting from information such as the survival rate, genome size, number of genes or gene density... I heard about a similar estimation for EMS mutagenesis (I don't remember the exact details but it was a correlation between number of colonies surviving the treatment and the number of point mutations per kb of genome). I cannot find the source of this kind of estimate so I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the kind of data and experiment you have please, as it will help people give you a better answer. If you have genotyped your colonies, then I would imagine it's not too hard to estimate the number of mutations which have occured.

Comment: I just did UV mutagenesis on my cells and determined a kill curve, that's all. I do not have genotyped my WT or MUT colonies (I'm not looking at a specific gene). 
My question is if there is a way to have a very very rough idea of how many changes I introduced in the genome by just correlating the survival at a specific dose to the genome size / number of essential genes or similar ( I know this requres lots of assuptions but that will be fine).